# WooCommerce Exclude Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking to exclude a Category from the Shop home page of my woocommerce store.

The loop I am using is the default loop internal to the plugin. I am not using a shortcode to call in the loop, nor am I using a custom php query.

The Shop home page is set to display every category. From there the user clicks through the various child categories until the appropriate products are revealed.

I have crawled through every conceivable solution within this website, none of which have has any effect – I'm hoping someone can help.

I want the exclude the following category:

**Category Name:** Z_PRODUCT CATALOGUE

**ID:** 122

**Slug:** product-catalogue

Examples of code I have attempted to use but failed:

```
function se_customize_product_shortcode( $args, $atts ) {
    if ( is_page( 'products' ) ) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'product-catalogue' ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
       );
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'se_customize_product_shortcode', 10, 2 );
```

and

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_query_exclude_products', 900, 1 );
function custom_query_exclude_products( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || is_search() || is_shop() ) return $query;


        $query->set( 'tax_query', array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'product-catalogue' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ) ) );


    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_query_exclude_products' );

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works for me. It's based on this [woocommerce support article](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/exclude-a-category-from-the-shop-page/). You need to put the *slug* for your excluded category in the `terms` array; double check that you have the right slug.

```php
/**
 * Exclude out-of-print products from the shop / search pages
 * "tax" here means "taxonomy" (a WordPress thing for handling product and other categories).
 * It doesn't mean "sales tax".
 */
function mystore_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'out-of-print' ), // Don't display products in the out-of-print category on the shop page.
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'mystore_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

I use the `woocommerce_product_query` action hook, but you try to use the `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` filter hook.

It generally takes about six years at the WordPress equivalent of the Hogwarts Academy of Magic to learn what each arcane hook does.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly this did not work for me. I have however found a soltuion which worked.

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'sct_hide_cat', 10, 3 );
function sct_hide_cat( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    $new_terms = array();
    if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'product-catalogue' ) ) ) {
                $new_terms[] = $term;
            }
        }
        $terms = $new_terms;
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain why this code works for you ? Also, you mean the other answer didn't work for you ?